# Ring homomorphism is surjective iff image of ideal is ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

I am searching for requirements that a **ring homomorphism** $f: A \to B$ must meet in order that it maps arbitrary **ideal**s $I \subset A$ to **ideal**s $f(I) \subset B$.

My thought was that the requirement is that $f$ must be **surjective**. That is

$f$ surjective $\Longleftrightarrow f(I)$ ideal in $B$

---

The $\Rightarrow$ direction was easy and straightforward (in fact there are multiple questions here that deal with this direction).

I'm struggling with showing that $f$ is **surjective** if we require $f(I)$ ideal in $B$. Especially for non-trivial elements in $B$ that are not contained in $f(I)$.

---

My initial assumption that $f$ should be **surjective** might also be wrong, I'm not sure since I am unable to prove $\Leftarrow$. Can you hint me into the right direction?

Comment: Your rings have a unit element? Are ring homomorphisms required to map $1$ to $1$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes and yes. The rings contain $1$ as neutral element for $\cdot$ and $f(1) = 1$. And also $1 \ne 0$.

Comment: Are ideals required to be proper? Or is $A$ an ideal of $A$?

Comment: @Zabuza: As an aside, it's a little weird to include $1 \neq 0$ in the definition of ring.

Comment: @Hurkyl No, $A$ is allowed to be an ideal of $A$.

Comment: It's good to have a little bit of skepticism for the problem you want to prove.  Think about what this is saying for fields, where the only ideals are zero and the whole ring.

Comment: @D_S Yeah, that's actually a good hint. Didn't thought of that, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A$ is an ideal of $A$, the requirement that a map $f : A \to B$ sends ideals to ideals implies that $f(A)$ is an ideal of $B$.

However, $f(A)$ is an ideal of $B$ containing $1_B$, and thus $f(A) = B$. So $f$ is surjective, as required.

---

The theorem is no longer true if we merely require $f$ to map proper ideals to ideals. For example if $A$ is a field, then its only proper ideal is the zero ideal, and thus *every* ring homomorphism $f : A \to B$ has the property that it sends proper ideals to ideals.

Comment: Why is $1_B \in f(A)$?

Comment: @Zabusa: $1_B = f(1_A)$ and $1_A \in A$.

Comment: Sorry, what confused me in the first place is why $1_A \in A$. I mean ideals aren't required to contain $1$, are they?

Comment: @Zabuza: Ideals of $A$ aren't required to contain $1_A$. $A$ is the only ideal of $A$ that contains every element of $A$.

Comment: Ah now I see. Sorry I got confused by $A$. I thought it would be $I$ that may be less than $A$. But you are actually using $A$ itself, which obviously contains $1_A$ and thus gets mapped to an ideal that contains $1_B$ and thus $A$ gets mapped to $B$.